# Creating a circuit of 3 LEDs of 3V from a 12V source

Tags: led, resistors

So I want to add some LEDs to my PC. I've bought SMD LEDs from eBay and now I want to connect them in several  group of three's LEDs and finally connect those groups I'm series (multiple sets of three LEDs connected in series). Some values of LEDs are,

1.LED Emitter: 0.5W
2.Output Lumens: 55-60LM
3.DC Forward Voltage (VF) :3.0 - 3.2 / DC
4.DC Forward Currect (IF) : 100 - 140 mA

What resistor will I need?  Also here power source is SMPS of the CPU. It has 9V as well as 12V output. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why the op-amp tag?

Comment: resistors limit current flowing into the LED. LEDs are driven by current sources. resistor is an approximate current source.

If you have 3 LED's like this with Vf=3V then you have 9V drop across the LED's; and assuming each LED requires 100mA to run; you have ((12-9)V/100mA) = 25 ohm. Calculating the power loss at the resistor P= I^2* R = (100mA)^2 * 25 = 1/4W. So you need a 25 ohm 1/4W resistor in series with 3 LED's with a 12V supply. (these are ideal calculations; please have some safety margin)

Comment: @ammar.cma Stop answering in comments, write a real answer so it can be voted and accepted.

Answer (score 2):

resistors limit current flowing into the LED. LEDs are driven by current sources. resistor is an approximate current source. If you have 3 LED's like this with Vf=3V then you have 9V drop across the LED's; and assuming each LED requires 100mA to run; you have ((12-9)V/100mA) = 25 ohm. Calculating the power loss at the resistor P= I^2* R = (100mA)^2 * 25 = 1/4W. So you need a 25 ohm 1/4W resistor in series with 3 LED's with a 12V supply. (these are ideal calculations; please have some safety margin)

Answer (score 0):

3 in series plus resistor. Then multiple Parallel groups of these. Multiple series groups won't work.

Resistor is calculated as (Vf - Vsource) / If = Resistor in Ohms. Then (Vf - Vsource) * If = Power Of Resistor  (round up generously).